# Better way to change between several background images with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, image, background

Is there a better way to write this function than just repeat it for each image change option?

I have a series of buttons which change the background image of a group of div's with the same class name, just want to know if there is a quicker or better way to do it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('#redbrick').click(function() {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/red-brick-wall.jpg)');
    });
    $('#brownbrick').click(function() {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/brown-brick-wall.jpg)');
    });
    $('#blackbrick').click(function() {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/black-brick-wall.jpg)');
    });
    $('#grass').click(function() {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/green-grass.jpg)');
    });
    $('#timber').click(function() {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/timber-bg.jpg)');
    });
    });
</script>
```

```html
      <button id="redbrick">Red Brick</button>
      <button value="brownbrick" id="brownbrick">Brown Brick</button>
      <button value="blackbrick" id="blackbrick">Black Brick</button>
      <button value="grass" id="grass">Grass</button>
      <button value="timber" id="timber">Timber</button>

<div id="a1" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a2" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a3" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a4" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a5" class="imagebg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Store the desired image name inside the `data-*` attribute of a button
- Don't forget to always use `type="button"` for your `<button>` elements that are not type of submit.

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope.

  const $imagebg = $('.imagebg');

  $("[data-bg]").on("click", function() {
    $imagebg.css({backgroundImage: `url(bg/${this.dataset.bg}.jpg)`});
  });

});
```

```html
<button type="button" data-bg="red-brick-wall">Red Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="brown-brick-wall">Brown Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="black-brick-wall">Black Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="green-grass">Grass</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="timber-bg">Timber</button>

<div class="imagebg"></div>
<div class="imagebg"></div>
```

Demo:

```js
jQuery($ => { // DOM ready and $ alias in scope.

  const $imagebg = $('.imagebg');

  $("[data-bg]").on("click", function() {
    console.log(this.dataset.bg)
    $imagebg.css({
      backgroundImage: `url(http://placehold.it/960x600/b0f/fff&text=${this.dataset.bg}`
    });
  });

});
```

```css
.imagebg {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-bg="red-brick-wall">Red Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="brown-brick-wall">Brown Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="black-brick-wall">Black Brick</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="green-grass">Grass</button>
<button type="button" data-bg="timber-bg">Timber</button>

<div class="imagebg"></div>
<div class="imagebg"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Roko, I cant seem to get that working, DW just says syntax error where ever I place that script, head or body....Im asuming that $imagebg is being set as .imagebg....i dont get what [data-change-brick] is.and how it gets used apart from that reference to it

Comment: @dragon_sa wups, I left a wrong selector throughout my edits. Should have been the shorter `$("[data-bg]")` Fixed :)

Comment: @dragon_sa PS instead of `this.dataset.bg` (pure JS) you can also use `$(this).data("bg")`

Comment: It is throwing an uncaught error in the inspector, but it all looks closed to me......Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'.....

Comment: I changed to the other method you suggested ($(this).data("bg")) and I also added CDATA tags, I also tried changing the accents either side of url, and tried in head tag and at the bottom of the body tag......this is the jquery lib I am using if that makes any difference or not.....<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @dragon_sa added another example if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to simplify the code by doing this

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    // change background image of results
    function bgChange(bgID) {
        $('.imagebg').css('background-image', 'url(bg/' + bgID + '.jpg)');
    }
</script>
```

```html
<button type="button" id="red-brick-wall" onClick="bgChange(this.id)">Red Brick</button>
<button type="button" id="brown-brick-wall" onClick="bgChange(this.id)">Brown Brick</button>
<button type="button" id="black-brick-wall" onClick="bgChange(this.id)">Black Brick</button>
<button type="button" id="green-grass" onClick="bgChange(this.id)">Grass</button>
<button type="button" id="timber-bg" onClick="bgChange(this.id)">Timber</button>

<div id="a1" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a2" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a3" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a4" class="imagebg"></div>
<div id="a5" class="imagebg"></div>
```

so the button id is the image name that gets passed into the css